# Reporting Server SSRS 2012 Weekdayname expression #Error

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

have this expression  (ssrs 2012)

**=weekdayname(weekday(today())-2)**

should return Saturday but instead returns #Error

works for every day expect Saturday.

Any work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to substract 2 from the results of `weekday()`, not 2 from `today()`. `weekday()` simply returns and integer and 2 - 2 = 0 which has no weekdayname.

You want to substract 2 days from today like this:

```
=weekdayname(weekday(dateadd("d", -2, today()))
```

Comment: thanks it worked =weekdayname(weekday(dateadd("d", -1, today())))

Comment: When using DateAdd, it is far more helpful to be explicit with the datepart.  eg. DateAdd(**Day**,-2,Today()) which is easier to understand and less likely to make mistakes (with months and minutes for instance)...